# Set PHP cookie with Ternary Operator to expire in a week

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, ternary-operator, setcookie

Trying to set a ternary php cookie to presist for a week, but adding time as the 3rd argument of 'setcookie' does not work. The cookie is count the amount of times a form is submitted.

Currently works as a SESSION cookie only:

```
setcookie('formCount', isset($_COOKIE['formCount']) ? ++$_COOKIE['formCount'] : 0);
            $formSubmits = ++$_COOKIE['formCount'];
```

I tried to set a 7 day (604800 second) persisting cookie like this:

```
setcookie('formCount', isset($_COOKIE['formCount'], 604800) ? ++$_COOKIE['formCount'] : 0);
            $formSubmits = ++$_COOKIE['formCount'];
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you pass two parameters to `setcookie` and two, including the timestamp, to `isset` so the expire parameter will be set to 0. What you want to do looks like this:

```
setcookie("formCount", isset($_COOKIE["formCount"]) ? ++$_COOKIE["formCount"] : 0, 604800);
```

Comment: This was the answer, but it actually didn'y work unless I added 'time()+' so 
setcookie("formCount", isset($_COOKIE["formCount"]) ? ++$_COOKIE["formCount"] : 0, time()+604800);